# Unwanted indent in large subsection titles

Tags: sectioning

It seems that no ones asked this before. I have an unwanted indent in the second line of the subsection title. I was wondering if anybody knows how to get rid of it. Near I provide a minimal example. Thanks in advance!

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}
    \usepackage{cmap}                   
    \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
    \usepackage[english,portuguese, main=russian]{babel}    

    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}


    \begin{document}
    \section{Section One}
    \subsection{The heading of this subsection is too long to fit in just one line. The indent after the first line is unwanted}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Your document, when compiled on my system, does not look like your posted output.  Rather, the section and subsection are numbered, and the rows of the subsection title are left aligned.

Comment: Hi Steven! Yeap it's weird... When I compile this piece of code online in Share LaTeX it looks normal as you've just said. But in TeXStudio that I use on my desktop it looks like on the image I provided above...

Comment: Perhaps you should check to see if some of your packages are out of date...

Comment: `titlesec` once had a bug that removed the numbering. An update should fix that. Check the log file where `article.cls` is being loaded from. You might have a changed version.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B Sorry for the late reply. Yes, it worked for me. I managed to update it manually, not through the `tlmgr` package manager.

Comment: We marked the question as a duplicate. Still, you got an upvote ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by manually updating the `titlesec` package from 2.10.1 version to 2.10.2, not through the `tlmgr` package manager. The section numbering was restored, titles of the sections are displayed correctly.